# Displaying an android app as a website

Tags: android, web

I know that a website can be displayed on an android app using a WebView. I have created an android application and I want to know if there is a way to display an android application as a website. Is this possible?

Comment: why do people down vote questions by amateur users? It's not like I'm asking a frequently asked question again. I searched everywhere online and I asked here because I thought people here are friendly and will help me. Looks like I'm wrong :(

Comment: Yes. There are different Hybrid platform that allow you to write application in HTML, CSS and JQuery.  e.g PhoneGap [http://phonegap.com/ ]. The application main feature rather then plug-in for mobile hardware support could be work on  browser also. As far as native app is concern, it cannot b e work on browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.you can't. Native Mobile functionality are totally different from websites. So you can't convert native android app to website type of application. Instead you can use hybrid application like sencha,titanium, jquery which is flexible to support in all mobile platforms and also website.